# pin an object with non-primitive data in c#

Tags: c#, object, garbage-collection, unmanaged

i have a communication-interface to a machine and got a dll provided with lots of functions to use. it all works fine, as long as i have communication going on. if there is nothing to communicate for let's say 5 minutes, the functions don't work anymore. i guess it is because it all gets cleaned up by the garbage collector. after some research i should probably pin it with `GCHandle.Alloc(object, GCHandleType.Pinned);`

here is some of the code:

the object

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class DNCC_PARAM
{
    public int nMacNo;
    public int nOwnPort;
    public int nIpAddr;
    public int nNCPort;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public Delegate CallBackFunction;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public short[] arrTimeout = new short[20];

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public short[] arrRetry = new short[20];
}
```

some dll imports

```
[DllImport(@"path to dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int Initialize([In()] DNCC_PARAM dncPara);

[DllImport(@"path to dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int dncc_Connect(int hdl);

[DllImport(@"path to dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int dncc_Disconnect(int hdl);
```

instance of the object

```
DNCC_PARAM param = new DNCC_PARAM();
```

initializing the communication

```
// fill the object with some data
param.nMacNo = 1;
param.nOwnPort = 7005;
param.nIpAddr = (int)IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.10").Address;
param.nNCPort = 7005;
param.CallBackFunction = new TypeOfCallBackFunction(AppCallBack);

// init the communication
nDNCC_HANDLE = Initialize(param);
```

the callback function

```
private void AppCallBack(int iHandle, int iEvent, IntPtr arg)
{
    // doing some stuff here
}
```

so when i try to pin the object like that `GCHandle.Alloc(param, GCHandleType.Pinned);` i get a message that the object does not contain primitive data. how can i prevent the object from being cleared by the GC?

my current "solution" is a timer which gets some communication going on every minute or so. i works but is rather ugly i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.100).aspx). The point being here that the managed object you've allocated doesn't have a memory layout that corresponds to the unmanaged layout that you're trying to describe via the `MarshalAs` attributes. So, you need the `Marshal` class to create an unmanaged *copy* of the structure that does have the desired layout.

`GCHandle` can only be used when the managed and unmanaged memory layouts are the same, and so the same memory can be used.

Comment: can you provide an example for my case?